# PIL im.putdata(seq, scale, offset) distance offset fail or I take it wrong?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, offset

From PIL, I tried to use putdata(seq, offset=distance) on and image im.
However, the result is not the offest of the distance as usual understanding to the offset which also appears in ImageChops.offset() and Image.offset().
It finally resulted a offset of the colour.

For example, the original image im is with the data p:

```
p = list(im.getdata())
p[:100]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,......]    #make the entries 0 for easy viewing
```

My original purpose is to offset im by 9 pixels. However,

```
im.putdata(p, offset=9)
newp=list(im.getdata())
newp[:100]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9,......]    #result is 9 units "offset" in colour!!
```

It resulted in offseting my image's color by 9 units!!
Does the putdata() method really offset the color only or I did something wrong? The PIL official documentation did not specify the offset is for distance(I supposed) or colour.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PIL documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm):

```
pixel = value * scale + offset
```

Can't be much clearer than that, the pixel values themselves are being offset, not their location.

Maybe you could make `paste` or `offset` work for you.

Comment: Yeh! OK, maybe I missed the very information from this expression. I sometimes get a headache for some math expression, indeed. Anyway, thank you very much for your reminding. However, I think if it were a distance offset, it would have made more sense and more useful to me in solving the Python Challenge lev 16 question. Peace!